# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Анализируя характер среды, а для подвижных уплотнений и параметры взаимного перемещения вводят дополнительные критерии для выбора материала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После "перемещения" запятая, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я просто думала - вдруг еще тире...

Comment: Тире полезно добавить после "уплотнений": в этом месте опущено подразумеваемое "анализируя", и тире "освежит" действие ранее использованного деепричастия.